# Unable to Configure WCF client for unit test execution error with basicHttpsBinding could not be found

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, resharper

Attempting to setup a unit test that calls a WCF service. Running under NET4.6  The client uses the basicHttpsBinding.

Have copied the system.serviceModel config section across (which includs the basicHttpsBinding tags to the unit Test's app.config.

When I run the test (xUnit) I get the following error when the Client constructor runs.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' in System.Configuration.dll

Additional information: Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/basicHttpsBinding' could not be found. 
Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly.
```

Another answer suggested adding the following (to ensure at least net4.5 is in executd for the test.

```
<startup>
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>   
</startup>
```

Any clues?

Edit:  This is only failing under resharper 10 Test Runer.  If I use CTRL-R, T and run against the InBuild runner it works fine.

I have tried a few options in Resharper,

- force CLR to 4.5,
- disable/enable shadow copy, and
- run in own
  appDomain.

none changed the result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious reasons for this to fail - the xunit plugin (now a part of ReSharper itself as of version 2016.1) does work with app.config files. If you could [log an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com), and ideally attach the solution (you can do so privately, so only JetBrains staff can see, or we can do NDA if required) I can take a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is similar to why my similar WCF ordered tests fail under the Microsoft tools...Running a single test works because it is run directly out of \bin\Debug...but running multiple units as an ordered test fails because to run it Microsoft uses an executable sandbox called QTAgentXXXXX.exe.

To find out what executable is running your tests, simply break point early on, and dump out the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation (note the TargetFrameworkName and ApplicationName properties specifically) and also dump out a call to System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileVersionInfo to get the executable path.
Load this executable into ILSpy and you can check out the framework it was compiled against.

The Microsoft QTAgent apps are under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\  and there seems to exist several varieties depending on the .Net Framework being used or whatever weird detection scheme they use to pick one....
UNFORTUNATELY, I observe that the most recent QTAgent32_40.exe is compiled under the old 4.0 Framework and before you ask, yes there is a QTAgent32_40.exe.config and no, adding the supportedRuntime setting with sku=4.6 does not encourage it to operate any differently (Maybe you would see different results tweaking your resharper 10 Test Runer config though).  And I've tried the assemblyBinding appliesTo attribute trick mentioned in several threads to no avail as well.
I attempted to use ILSpy to recompile my own version of QTAgent against 4.6.2 but a lot of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.blah.blah assemblies being referenced have a lot of internal classes that you cannot build against. These assemblies have this crappy assembly attribute called InternalsVisibleTo which lists what external libraries and executables are allowed access to these internal classes.  The QTAgent executables are among these attributes, which is why they can use them from those assemblies.  So it would be a very long and deep rabbit hole to see if one could essentially decompile ALL these related assemblies and recompile the unit testing framework.  That is a lot of research for such a small gain.  I say screw Microsoft's Unit Testing framework.  It is fraught with other issues as well.  My co-worker keeps suggesting to use NUnit.  I think I may give it a try.